# how to count the number of loops that meet specific criteria in sql

Tags: mysql, loops, session, count

On a MySQL database, I have the table below (it is a panel data of customers)

```html
 
user |  tab   |   action    |    time| 

77      -          login      1407171344
77    user-info    view       1407171400
77    traffic      select     1407171407
77      -          login      1407171440
65      -          login      1407171505
65    change       select     1407564830
65    change       pay        1407579352
65      -          login      1407579442
65      -          login      1407579765
77      -          login      1407579866
77      -          login      1407680000
77    promotion    bank       1407171400
77    promotion    pay        1408100946
65    traffic      select     1407171400
65    traffic      pay        1408114734
65      -          login      1408125796
65    service      extend     1408192741
```

I have many rows with different customer ids. I want to count the number of active sessions for each customer. That is, I want to count the number of times a customer logs in and does another action/actions after login. So two consecutive logins with no actions in between do not count for a session. The end of a session can be proxied by next login. For user 77, the first three rows (action:login,select,view) comprise a session, but next login does not because no other action is taken. Thus, In the table above user 77 has two active sessions and user 75 has 3 active session.

Active sessions will be as below: (repeated logins will no action are deleted)

```html
user |  tab   |   action    |    time| 

77      -          login      1407171344
77    user-info    view       1407171400
77    traffic      select     1407171407
65      -          login      1407171505
65    change       select     1407564830
65    change       pay        1407579352
65      -          login      1407579765
77      -          login      1407680000
77    promotion    bank       1407171400
77    promotion    pay        1408100946
65    traffic      select     1407171400
65    traffic      pay        1408114734
65      -          login      1408125796
65    service      extend     1408192741
```

How can I count active sessions? Thanks in advance.

P.S. I have tried importing data in R but it is a big data and R seemed very slow with loops. So I am trying to stick to SQL as much as possible.

Comment: we tried to write the loop and searched on the web including this website, we realized it may be the case that indexing is not possible in sql. So far failed. If we know how to start of if we become sure there is a way for recoding this in sql we will show you the code.  So is there a way??

Comment: You don't write loops in SQL, you write joins or use `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume users can't have multiple sessions at the same time, 
If they do then you need to track them differently using a 3rd parameter.
Let's assume your data is already in table user_action and at present 
it looks like:

```
SELECT  user,action,time  FROM user_action  order by user, time;
user    activity    time
65  select      1407171400
65  login       1407171505
65  select      1407564830
65  pay         1407579352
65  login       1407579442
65  login       1407579765
65  pay         1408114734
65  login       1408125796
65  extend      1408192741
77  login       1407171344
77  bank        1407171400
77  view        1407171400
77  select      1407171407
77  login       1407171440
77  login       1407579866
77  login       1407680000
77  pay         1408100946
```

Copy records ordered by user and then by time
, with a new column activity number --> into a new temp table for analysis

The last session of each customer may not have a login record to signify end of session, so we add a login row for each customer a the end of their sessions.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS user_action_temp;
SET @activity_number := 0;
CREATE TABLE  user_action_temp
AS 
SELECT @activity_number := @activity_number + 1 AS activity_number, user, action, time
FROM
(SELECT  user,action,time  FROM user_action 
UNION SELECT user,'login' as action,max(time)+1 as time  FROM user_action GROUP BY user) AS USER_ACTIVITY
ORDER BY user, time;
```

Your data now looks like:

```
select * From user_action_temp order by user, time;
activity_number user    action      time
1       65  select      1407171400
2       65  login       1407171505
3       65  select      1407564830
4       65  pay         1407579352
5       65  login       1407579442
6       65  login       1407579765
7       65  pay         1408114734
8       65  login       1408125796
9       65  extend      1408192741
10      65  login       1408192742
11      77  login       1407171344
12      77  bank        1407171400
13      77  view        1407171400
14      77  select      1407171407
15      77  login       1407171440
16      77  login       1407579866
17      77  login       1407680000
18      77  pay         1408100946
19      77  login       1408100947
```

Next, self-join this table by itself 
Let's define two variables to set login number for each login activity .

```
SET @login_number1:=0;
SET @login_number2:=0;
```

Self-join the table on login number from table 1 matches the next login in table 2 and user remains the same.
Activity count is total activities between two logins

```
SELECT * FROM
(
SELECT logins_1.user,
logins_1.time as session_start,
logins_2.time as session_end, 

case when (logins_2.activity_number -logins_1.activity_number )>1 
then (logins_2.activity_number -logins_1.activity_number - 1) else 0 end  
as activity_count

FROM
    (SELECT @login_number1 := @login_number1 + 1 AS login_number, 
    activity_number, user, action, time 
    FROM user_action_temp 
    WHERE action='login' 
    ORDER BY user, time) AS logins_1
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (SELECT @login_number2 := @login_number2 + 1 AS login_number2,
     activity_number, user, action, time  
    FROM user_action_temp 
    WHERE action='login' 
    ORDER BY user, time) AS logins_2
on logins_1.login_number = (logins_2.login_number2-1) 
and logins_1.user = logins_2.user

) AS RESULT;
```

Which gives summary of all user sessions:

```
user    session_start   session_end activity_count
65  1407171505  1407579442  2
65  1407579442  1407579765  0
65  1407579765  1408125796  1
65  1408125796  1408192742  1
65  1408192742  <null>  0
77  1407171344  1407171440  3
77  1407171440  1407579866  0
77  1407579866  1407680000  0
77  1407680000  1408100947  1
77  1408100947  <null>  0
```

You can filter the above query using `WHERE activity_count>0` to get what you want.

Comment: Thanks a lot. you answered our other questions as well in the way you got the output! Because we also wanted to count specific actions in each session....We are trying this and will post errors if there is any.